# Tab.js Cannot read property 'getSelectorFromElement' of undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, tabs

I am trying to set up tabs for my Bootstrap project. I have copied and pasted the provided tab example from https://bootstrap.algolia.com/javascript/#tabs into my own project while adding

`$('#myTabs a').click(function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  $(this).tab('show');
});`

Unfortunately, my console is returning the following error:

```
Cannot read property 'getSelectorFromElement' of undefined
```

I have also added the id "myTabs" to the main UL element of the tab list. Ideas on why my tabs are not showing the corresponding data on click of each tab?

Answer (score 6):

Try to insert the util.js file of bootstrap in your HTML:

```
<script src="bootstrap/js/dist/util.js"></script>
```

Comment: same is true for bootstrap modal.js

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same problem. It seems the JS example throws those errors. I commented out the following code and my tabs worked perfectly:

```js
  //  $('#myTabs a').click(function(e){
  //    e.preventDefault();
  //    $(this).tab('show');
  //  });
```